# download file from remote server by php?

Tags: php, ftp, ftps

Someone tells me. if it is possible for me to download a specific file from a remote server at my location via php?

I've tried codes and I couldn't

```
    <?php

// define some variables
$local_file = '/httpdocs/teste.pdf';
$server_file = 'teste.pdf';
$ftp_server="209.126.127.143";
$ftp_user_name="username";
$ftp_user_pass="password";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Comment: do you get any error(s), what have you done to debug your issue?

Comment: receive this error when downloading the file on the remote server at my location >
Warning: ftp_get(/httpdocs/teste.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/LDL/api/ftpdow.php on line 16

Warning: ftp_get(): Error opening /httpdocs/teste.pdf in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/LDL/api/ftpdow.php on line 16
There was a problem

Comment: `httpdocs != htdocs`

Comment: Can you download that file using any (GUI) FTP client using the same credentials? => Show us its log file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can download a folder. Try to include filename in `$server_file`

```
ftp_get($conn_id, './teste.pdf', '/httpdocs/teste.pdf', FTP_BINARY)
```

Also, `/httpdocs/` should be relative from your FTP user's home folder

Comment: will i be clearer i want to download a file from an ftp host outside my location and download it at my location? this is possible I never did it

Comment: I get a warning error as he was looking for the file on the site not on the remote host

Comment: Warning: ftp_get(/httpdocs/teste.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/LDL/api/ftpdow.php on line 16 Warning: ftp_get(): Error opening /httpdocs/teste.pdf in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/LDL/api/ftpdow.php on line 16 There was a problem

Comment: The thing that unclear is what is the file path on FTP server, and where you want to put downloaded file? For example, if the file on server is on root folder called `/serverfile.pdf` and you want to save it on current folder, try `ftp_get($conn_id, './downloaded.pdf', '/serverfile.pdf', FTP_BINARY)`. From your code, it seems to look for folder `httpdocs` on ROOT (/) for download, not current directory. To use current working directory, add DOT (.) before slash